# What is the difference between "Ich geh" and "Ich geh mit mir"?

Tags: meaning

I heard it in a song:

> "Ich geh mit mir von Ost nach Süd".

But isn't this the same as "Ich geh"? It was in response to the question: "Wohin gehst du?"

Is it expressing loneliness somehow? Are there two "Ich"? Einer der geht und einer der mitgeht? Does it mean to go alone? By yourself?

Comment: It would help what song it was.

Comment: @infinitezero Mein Land by Rammstein.

Comment: It's not about loneliness. It's about separation. You might figure it out by comparing *Ich gehe mit dir.* vs. *Ich gehe mit mir.* if you consider the rest of the lyrics.

Comment: @Olafant Do they sing Ich geh mit dir?

Comment: [No. They don't.](https://genius.com/Rammstein-mein-land-lyrics)

Comment: @Olafant Why does that mean separation? Countries separate but I dont see the connection.

Comment: @Olafant I think I get you!

Comment: @Olafant Thats what I mean. I know the text by heart. Great song (if you take it ironically, which some cant...). Da kommt er angerannt, mit der Fahne in der Hand,

Comment: I'd think that provoking the kind of question you're asking was the precise purpose of using this construction.

Comment: @KilianFoth Is is not a normal usage? Doesnt every German use it? Its a provoking song indeed. At the end: VERTRIEBEN...VERTREIBEN...VERGESSEN. It gives me the shivers! In fact I have just looked at it.

Comment: I would say, the last line in Verse 2 supports the theory that the "ich" is going on this journey alone: "Ich geh von Land zu Land allein". And no, it is absolutely not normal usage. If you said that to a German they would probably raise an eyebrow or ask a clarifying question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ich geh mit mir von Ost nach Süd

is nothing you would usually say. It's part of the [lyrics](https://genius.com/Rammstein-mein-land-lyrics) of the song *Mein Land* by the band *Rammstein*.

It's not a normal German sentence. So the question

> What is the difference between "Ich geh" and "Ich geh mit mir"?

can not be answered in a grammatical sense. You need to interpret it considering the rest of the lyrics and you better try to do that yourself instead of asking for the interpretation of others. Let me provide some hints to make it easier for you:

> Ich gehe mit **dir** ...
> (I go with you ...)

is a normal German phrase. It's inviting and connective.

> Ich gehe mit **mir** ...

is quite the opposite, especially since it doesn't really make sense. As @KilianFoth mentioned in a comment: provoking the kind of question you're asking might be the precise purpose of using this construction.

> Ich gehe mit **mir** ...

is (considering the rest of the lyrics) everything but inviting. It's not about loneliness here, it's about separation.